# How to share ubuntu directory for Windows 7 but cannot see files inside?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

I would like to install and run windows applicaion from ubuntu share directory. But I don't want Windows 7 (or Windows XP) client to see or can copy file within that directory. For example, I have application name CustomerHist.exe that need to read database inside subdirectory name DATA, my purpose is other user can run this application, but cannot see or view files inside DATA subdirectory.

PS.Thanks for every reply, and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Permission structure in Linux is different than the one on windows machines. In Linux you only have r,w,x permission while you have some extra ones on windows. Also in Linux you can give these three types of permission for three types of users; owner,group and others. So for a file, if you want it to have full permissions for owner, only execute permission for group and others , assign 711 to it. For to change permissions you will use chmod command. To share this folder to win users you will need to use samba.